# Vue 3 mapGetters problem mutliple getters not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

My getters

```
const state = {
    pakets: [
        { id: 1, paketname: "Simple", price: "5" },
        { id: 2, paketname: "Silver", price: "10" },
        { id: 3, paketname: "Gold", price: "15" },
        { id: 4, paketname: "Platin", price: "25" },
    ],
    basket:[],
}

 const getters = {
   getBaskets(state){
     return state.basket
   },
   getTotal(state){
     let total = 0;
     state.basket.forEach(x=> this.total += 1 * x.price)
     return total;
   }
 }
```

My component

```
<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  computed:{
    ...mapGetters([
        'getBaskets',
        'getTotal'
    ]),
  },
};
</script>
```

**Hi everyone  I wrote a basket in my own project, but I want to calculate the total in this base. The mapgetter only works when it receives one getters, but it does not work when there are 2 or more, I can't find out what could be the reason. Thanks**

Comment: What exactly does not work? The question should contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . `this.total +=` - this should never happen in a getter, not to mention that you always return 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
const getters = {
  getBaskets: (state) => state.basket,
  getTotal: (state) => state.basket.reduce((acc, x) => acc += Number(x.price), 0)
}
```